# Are tricep overhead extensions shoulder healthy?

Tags: injury-prevention, dumbbells, shoulders, muscle-gain, triceps

The thing is, the movement of a dumbbell tricep extension looks so complex that I wonder if it is shoulder safe or not. Can one do triceps overhead extensions without damaging shoulders? And if not, what are some shoulder healthy ways to build tricep muscles up?

Comment: Shoulder healthy I'd vote standing overhead press. The bench press has a lot of tricep. Dips have a lot of tricep. Tricep extensions (skull crushers) can cause wicked DOMS and (in my opinion) overworks the elbows putting you the realm of tendinitis.

Comment: @EricKaufman I agree with you about the potential danger in doing triceps extensions, but I can personally attest that overhead shoulder press can be a real killer for someone who has impingement syndrome.  I'd actually choose the risk of tendonitis doing extensions over mashing my shoulder by doing standing presses.